# dynamically select columns from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic

I have a couple queries that lead in the dynamic part, but I think this should make sense

```
$memberID = 7;
$oreVolumePriceQuery = "SELECT od.oreID, od.oreType, od.name, od.inGameID, od.size, ir.officialCorpRate FROM oreData od JOIN itemRates ir ON od.inGameID = ir.typeID order by od.oreID asc";
$oreVolumePriceResult = mysql_query($oreVolumePriceQuery);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($oreVolumePriceResult)){
    $oreType = $row['oreType'];
    $getRefiningRateQuery = "SELECT '$oreType' FROM memberData WHERE member_id = '$memberID'";
    $getRefiningRateResult = mysql_query($getRefiningRateQuery);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getRefiningRateResult)){
    $refiningRate = $row['$oreType'];
```

The first query returns results similar to below (actually 31 lines, but 2 will be sufficient)

```
oreID | oreType | name     | inGameID | size | officialCorpRate
 1    | veld    | veldspar | 1230     | 0.1  | 10.21
 2    | scor    | scordite | 1228     | .15  | 10.2
```

Based on line one, the second query ends up being

```
SELECT veld FROM memberData WHERE member_ID = '7'
```

And this query returns the correct result of

```
veld
 .7
```

But this all falls apart on the last line, where it is dynamically choosing which column to pull from the query. Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: the best practice is that use a single query and fetch everything you need. Please give more information about your task

Comment: btw! when did you assign `$memberID` to any value?

Comment: @TheCOMPLETEPHPNewbie i have edited to assign $memberID

Answer (score 2):

you are defining two same $row name, rename the second fetch to $row1 forexemple

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($oreVolumePriceResult)){
$oreType = $row['oreType'];
$getRefiningRateQuery = "SELECT '$oreType' FROM memberData WHERE member_id = '$memberID'";
$getRefiningRateResult = mysql_query($getRefiningRateQuery);
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($getRefiningRateResult)){
$refiningRate = $row1[$oreType];
```

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, you should always add `mysql_error();` when your query is failing for unknown reason. So, Try this as I have made 3/4 changes:

```
$oreVolumePriceQuery = "SELECT od.oreID, od.oreType, od.name, od.inGameID, od.size, ir.officialCorpRate FROM oreData od JOIN itemRates ir ON od.inGameID = ir.typeID order by od.oreID asc";
$oreVolumePriceResult = mysql_query($oreVolumePriceQuery) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($oreVolumePriceResult)){
    $memberID = 7;
    $oreType = $row['oreType'];
    $getRefiningRateQuery = "SELECT '$oreType' FROM memberData WHERE member_id = '$memberID'";
    $getRefiningRateResult = mysql_query($getRefiningRateQuery) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getRefiningRateResult)){
    $refiningRate = $row['$oreType'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables in single quotes won't be evaluated, so instead of

```
$refiningRate = $row['$oreType'];
```

you probably want

```
$refiningRate = $row[$oreType];
```

Also, is there a reason you aren't just joining the memberData table to the original query?